# How to secure erase free space on a Mac

Tags: mac, hard-drive, secure-erase

I have a Macbook with an upgraded, but previously used hard drive.

I know that Macs have an option to 'securely delete' files, which essentially copies over all the file data with random 0's and 1's.

If possible, I would like to do this with all the unused space on my hard drive to clean it up.  I think this is similar to what defragmenting does, correct?

Anyway, how can this be accomplished?  Is there a way to do so with Disk Utility perhaps?  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite what defragmentation is. Defragmenting is where fragments of files are placed contiguously so that the drive seek times are reduced, making loading files into memory a little faster.

To do a secure erase of free space on your Mac, do the following in Disk Utility:

> Erasing free disk space does not erase
>   the other files on your disk.
>
> 1. In Disk Utility, select the disk or volume in the list with the free space
>      you want to erase.
> 2. Click Erase, then click the Erase Free Space button.
> 3. Select an option, then click Erase.

Source: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=diskutility/10.5/en/duh1010.html